# Clustering mixed data - SPSS

Tags: clustering, spss, data-imputation, mixed-type-data

On my current project, I have to form four or five clusters describing different types of banking customers. The data is based on a survey of around 3500 participants and contains more than 250 variables. Almost all variables are on a likert-scale, e.g. "My bank should provide branches nearby" or "Sustainable investments are important for me" ranging from 1 - I completely agree to 5 - I completely disagree.

Even though I've read different opinions on the subject, I decided to treat these variables as continuous (even though some argue they should be considered as categorical variables).

As a first step, I used a factor analysis, correlation matrices and subjective ideas to combine some of the variables to certain constructs (e.g. the statements "Sustainable investments are important for me" and "My bank should provide sustainable investments" describe the same construct). To obtain a value for each construct, I calculated the mean of the belonging variables. Overall, I obtained 20 different constructs that should be included in the cluster analysis.

Finally, I used the K-Means algorithm and got some promising results.

However, our client wants to include some other variables in the clustering process as well. Two of these variables describe the financial situation of the participants: Monthly net earnings (ordinal; ranging from 1 - nothing to 9 - 4000€ and more (in 500€ steps)) and monthly saving rate (ordinal; ranging from 1 - nothing to 11 - 1000€ and more (in 100€ steps)). Besides, a categorical variables should be included in the analysis: The residential area (1 - Living in a city / 2 - Living in a suburb / 3 - Living in a rural area).

So far, I face three different problems:

1. On the three aforementioned variables, the participants had the option to select the answer 99 - I don't want to answer this question. How do I treat observations with these answers? Should I define this code as missing values and impute them?
2. How do I handle the different scales of the ordinal variables? Can I just standardize all variables that should be included in the kmeans algorithm?
3. How can I deal with the categorical variable describing the residential area? Must I use two-step hierarchical clustering in this case? Does it actually make any sense to include this variable in the clustering process?

I'm a newcomer in this area and would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Actually, you are asking too many questions in one question. I would recommend you to break it into different posts. But first, before posting, you should make a local search for similar questions and topics. Things you are asking have been touched or covered many times on this site. Start with the search of tags "clustering" + "mixed type data"